# ubuntu 13.04 installation with liveusb

Tags: installation, 13.04, live-usb, uefi

I made a bootable USB using [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), mounting the .iso file on it and disabling the secure boot with UEFI mode on.

Now whenever I go to the BIOS menu, the option to boot from my USB drive shows up, but clicking on it does nothing and Windows 8 is booted.

What do I do?

Comment: What do you mean, you mounted the ISO?

Comment: it means i used universal usb installer for the .iso file to make the pen drive bootable

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a bootable USB flash using the ISO, and not just mounting it.  I recommend that you use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), and have a look at [Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

Comment: but i have used universal usb installer.will that be not sufficient?

Comment: Its sufficient, but you have to let it create the bootable USB.  All you have to do is select the distribution, and click create.  Just to be on the safe side, check the option to format the USB drive.

Comment: again i used the universal usb installer and as u said i selected the 13.04 iso distribution and clicked create with formatting.it got created successfully but again when i went to bios menu and selected loading from usb,it got directly loaded to windows 8.so what to do now?

Comment: Try UNetbootin as mentioned in my answer.  Are you creating under Windows?

Comment: Unetbootin does not have option for ubuntu 13.04..it has only till 12.10

Comment: I don't think that it matters.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, this just saved my ass! Worked like a champ for 13.04 ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I believe your boot order is wrong.

You are booting from the HD first so of course Windows boots. You need to change the boot order.

To do this you need to go into the bios menu, boot options, and scroll down to usb option and highlight it, hit  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>,then scroll the usb option to the top...then

Save and Exit = F10 I do believe.

"NOTE" → To scroll ↑ or ↓, on my laptop is F6= Scroll Down, and F7 = Scroll Up. It should tell you at the bottom of you bios screen which ones to use...

Hope this helps... Good Luck!